# Unable to uninstall VMWare Work Station on Windows 8.1

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I am facing an issue. When I try to uninstall VMWare,the following message is shown.

[image]

The MSI failed message. Even though I search in google and I didn't find a way to solve.

VMWare version was

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling it using elevated rights?

Try this:

- Right click on your start button and select "Command Prompt (Admin)".
- In the command prompt, type "control appwiz.cpl".
- The old style uninstall screen should open, so you can select "VMWare Player" from the list, then at the top, select "Change"
- In the pop up window, choose "Uninstall"

Comment: I already tried like that. But it was still showing the MSI failed message.